# What is this powerline infrastructure?

Tags: mains, overhead-lines

I am in the UK and often see this odd arrangement of rods bent toward one another on the guy wires of power cables. What are they for?

They almost look like a spark gap, but I’m sure they’re not as they're so far apart. Could they be to connect a conductor across to ground the guy wire? Why would that be desirable?

It seems to me that I see this on older looking installations, perhaps it is being phased out.

I spotted this one near Bury St Edmunds in Suffolk last week.

[image: Guy wire - context]
[image: Guy wire - detail]

Comment: May want to re-post on Home Improvement.

Comment: is there a turnbuckle? ... the two bent rods may be an indicator of a loosened turnbuckle if the two are misaligned ...

Comment: Not that I could tell - the parts between the rods appeared to be solid sheet metal, with wire spliced eyes around bolts at either end.

Comment: @SteveSh I don't see how this would be a better fit on Home Improvement; it's definitely more in the domain of electrical engineering.

Comment: My best guess it is a spark gap, but only for lightening. If there was a fault between one of the high voltage wires and the top of the guy wire you wouldn't want the lower part to become live where any passing member of the public might touch it. On the other hand it would be desirable that, in the event of a lightening strike on or near the pole, the current is diverted to ground as close as possible and not propagate further.

Comment: Arcing horns? @SteveSh is this home improvement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcing_horns second picture looks a lot like this

Comment: @JYelton - A lot of electricians (not EEs) seem to hang out on that site.

Comment: @SteveSh Fair enough; though I still think the subject matter should never be in the domain of "home" improvement or DIY! :)

Comment: @PeterJennings I think you mean "lightning" instead of "lightening," the latter of which is the opposite of darkening.

Comment: @JYelton I take it you've never experienced a darkning storm before.

Comment: @JYelton Yup, stupid spell checker, stupid me.

Comment: And not to be confused with Litening, which is a EO pod developed by Northrop Grumman.

Comment: Note that there is also a section disconnect *right here*.  Note the funny dinguses up there and the pole rod linkage running down the pole to ??? (motor drive??) It's possible this arc catcher is related to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arcing horns are there to protect the fibreglass strain insulator from flash-over.

Unlike a normal spark gap, this spark gap isn't there to provide a early spark to protect a building or equipment. This spark gap is only going to spark when there is enough voltage to flash over that entire strain insulator. And all it is going to protect is the insulator -- not anything of real value.

But when you get flashover along an insulator like that, it creates a low-impedance conductive path along the insulator. No real damage to anything important, but the insulator doesn't work correctly after that. And not even much visible damage that you can easily check.

So when there is a lightning strike nearby, the insulator is protected, then everything goes back to working as normal.

Comment: I think this is a good answer which I will accept tomorrow if there are no surprises. It would be wonderful if we could find some kind of citation of this guy wire arrangement to back it up - I’ve looked and been unsuccessful.

Comment: To be honest, I can't see well enough in the picture to be sure, and that structure is not used in my area -- I've only seen a gap like that in a test lab.